# htaccess assisting a php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have many pages my problem stands that I need to open all my php files and add a line of code at the top of each php page.

```
<?php 
if(!defined('no_d_a')){die('What The ... how did you get here :) ');} /* no direct access */ 
// rest of existing code here //
?>
```

Question is can I instead do this on a .htaccess file because I am feeling abit lazy :)

TIA

Comment: What constellation would grant access to those pages? A session, a cookie, a query string?

Comment: a defined constant lol as the if condition says it... :)

Comment: Ups, sorry, it's been early morning..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your wanting is a way to prepend the files with htaccess?   If so here ya go:

Save this as 'prepend.php'

```
<?php
  if(!defined('no_d_a')){} /* no direct access */ 
?>
```

in your .htaccess add:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/*******/public_html/prepend.php"
</FilesMatch>
```

it will prepend all .php files with 'prepend.php'

You may want to have some conditional clauses.. but that should get you started..

---

You can also append files with 'auto_append_file' instead of 'auto_prepend_file'

Comment: Was about to write about changing the php.ini directives, but applying it thru .htaccess seems cleaner and more appropriate.

Comment: It is actually great for when the code to prepend/append is not critical...  e.g. i often use it when customers want to add bbclone to an existing site..

Comment: What's the default for FilesMatch?

Comment: There is no 'default' for FilesMatch...  Files and FilesMatch are simply directives to limit the commands within them to the matched criteria (either filenames for specific "Files" or a regex for "FilesMatch"...  Check out the apache docs for more info on both.   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP ini setting called: [**`auto_prepend_file`**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), where you can set the name of a file wich will be included into every PHP script at the top!

You can now set this setting in your .htaccess like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file prepend.php
```

Check this [good tutorial](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend/)